# How to get date and time from a string using regx?

Tags: regex, python-3.6

I need to get a file updated time from an ftp and for this I am using regular expression to get date and time from following string-

```
'-rw-r--r--    1 sedangston sedangston   57087764 Aug  2 13:37 products.csv'
```

And my regular expression code to get date and time is as below-

```
ftp_updated_time = re.findall('[a-zA-Z ]+(?=\s\d ) +\s\d+:\d+', item)[0]
```

But I am getting `FTP:list out of index error` from above code.

Can anyone please correct my regx to get the date and time(Aug  2 13:37) from the string I have mentioned above?

Please note there is double space between Aug and 2 in above string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the regex causing the issue, `[a-zA-z]{3}  \d{1,2} \d\d:\d\d` should work.

Comment: The match will still have excessive whitespace if you only use this pattern.

Comment: And at least the `    ` should be replaced by `\s+`.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Since it's always going to be a double space, how much of a difference does `  ` vs `\s+` make?

Comment: It does not in this case (if indeed the string does not change), however for future readers I believe it would be useful to use `\s+`, for readability too.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `re.sub` and `re.findall` as follows:

```
date = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s\d\s+\d{2}:\d{2}',re.sub(r'(\s)\s+(?=\d\s\d{2}:\d{2})',r'\1',str))
```

`re.sub` removes excessive whitespace, `re.findall` finds the date.

```
>>print(date)
['Aug 2 13:37']
```

You can see how the `re.sub` pattern operates [here](https://regex101.com/r/Hx6dBk/8). 
You can check how the `re.findall` pattern operates [here](https://regex101.com/r/Hx6dBk/7).

Answer (score 0):

With dates, it is easy to be specific and location aware with the [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#module-calendar) module, a regex, and [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) to validate:

```
import calendar
import datetime as dt
import re 

def get_date(s):
    months=list(calendar.month_abbr)  # ['','Jan','Feb'...] for the location
    pat=re.compile(r'(\b({})[ \t]+(\d{{1,2}})[ \t]+(\d\d:\d\d)\b)'.format(r'|'.join(months[1:])))
    m=pat.search(s)
    if m and dt.datetime.strptime('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(m.group(2),m.group(3),m.group(4)),'%b\t%d\t%H:%M'):
        return m.group(1)
    else:
        return None
```